# Linux routing and port forwarding to a secondary network not working from WAN

Tags: linux, routing, port, forwarding

I have a linux box acting as a router, with two interfaces
· eth0 - 192.168.0.61
· as0t0 - 172.27.224.1

Network 192.168.2.0/24 is accesible through as0t0, so I have this routes:

```
[root@192.168.0.61 ~]# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         gateway         0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
172.27.224.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 as0t0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 as0t0
```

I also have a port forwarding rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 8123 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.245:8123
```

Currently a host of 192.168.0.0/24 can use the web server at 192.168.2.245:8123 perfectly, it does not work from host of the WAN. Main router is 192.168.0.251 with routes and port forwarding.

Packets reach 192.168.0.61 eth0, but they don't go through as0t0, and I do not know why.

As example, when the host 192.168.0.6 use a web browser to 192.168.0.61:8123 all works perfectly.

```
[root@192.168.0.61 ~]# tcpdump -i eth0 port 8123 -n
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
16:47:22.232044 IP 192.168.0.6.58898 > 192.168.0.61.8123: Flags [SEW], seq 361471277, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
16:47:22.305155 IP 192.168.0.61.8123 > 192.168.0.6.58898: Flags [S.], seq 226116772, ack 361471278, win 64240, options [mss 1258,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:47:22.305722 IP 192.168.0.6.58898 > 192.168.0.61.8123: Flags [.], ack 1, win 1027, length 0
16:47:22.305868 IP 192.168.0.6.58898 > 192.168.0.61.8123: Flags [P.], seq 1:601, ack 1, win 1027, length 600
16:47:22.446997 IP 192.168.0.61.8123 > 192.168.0.6.58898: Flags [.], ack 601, win 501, length 0
16:47:22.447020 IP 192.168.0.61.8123 > 192.168.0.6.58898: Flags [P.], seq 1:170, ack 601, win 501, length 169
16:47:22.447035 IP 192.168.0.61.8123 > 192.168.0.6.58898: Flags [P.], seq 170:230, ack 601, win 501, length 60
16:47:22.447484 IP 192.168.0.6.58898 > 192.168.0.61.8123: Flags [.], ack 230, win 1026, length 0
16:47:22.537873 IP 192.168.0.6.58898 > 192.168.0.61.8123: Flags [P.], seq 601:1431, ack 230, win 1026, length 830
16:47:22.646742 IP 192.168.0.61.8123 > 192.168.0.6.58898: Flags [.], ack 1431, win 501, length 0
16:47:22.646762 IP 192.168.0.61.8123 > 192.168.0.6.58898: Flags [P.], seq 230:400, ack 1431, win 501, length 170
16:47:22.646777 IP 192.168.0.61.8123 > 192.168.0.6.58898: Flags [P.], seq 400:570, ack 1431, win 501, length 170
16:47:22.647193 IP 192.168.0.6.58898 > 192.168.0.61.8123: Flags [.], ack 570, win 1024, length 0
...

[root@192.168.0.61 ~]# tcpdump -i as0t0 port 8123 -n
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on as0t0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
16:47:22.232111 IP 192.168.0.6.58898 > 192.168.2.245.8123: Flags [SEW], seq 361471277, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
16:47:22.305136 IP 192.168.2.245.8123 > 192.168.0.6.58898: Flags [S.], seq 226116772, ack 361471278, win 64240, options [mss 1258,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:47:22.305863 IP 192.168.0.6.58898 > 192.168.2.245.8123: Flags [.], ack 1, win 1027, length 0
16:47:22.305872 IP 192.168.0.6.58898 > 192.168.2.245.8123: Flags [P.], seq 1:601, ack 1, win 1027, length 600
16:47:22.446980 IP 192.168.2.245.8123 > 192.168.0.6.58898: Flags [.], ack 601, win 501, length 0
16:47:22.447013 IP 192.168.2.245.8123 > 192.168.0.6.58898: Flags [P.], seq 1:170, ack 601, win 501, length 169
16:47:22.447030 IP 192.168.2.245.8123 > 192.168.0.6.58898: Flags [P.], seq 170:230, ack 601, win 501, length 60
16:47:22.447495 IP 192.168.0.6.58898 > 192.168.2.245.8123: Flags [.], ack 230, win 1026, length 0
16:47:22.537892 IP 192.168.0.6.58898 > 192.168.2.245.8123: Flags [P.], seq 601:1431, ack 230, win 1026, length 830
16:47:22.646728 IP 192.168.2.245.8123 > 192.168.0.6.58898: Flags [.], ack 1431, win 501, length 0
16:47:22.646755 IP 192.168.2.245.8123 > 192.168.0.6.58898: Flags [P.], seq 230:400, ack 1431, win 501, length 170
16:47:22.646771 IP 192.168.2.245.8123 > 192.168.0.6.58898: Flags [P.], seq 400:570, ack 1431, win 501, length 170
16:47:22.647207 IP 192.168.0.6.58898 > 192.168.2.245.8123: Flags [.], ack 570, win 1024, length 0


pi@192.168.2.245:~ $ sudo tcpdump -i tun0 port 8123 -n
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
16:47:22.283238 IP 192.168.0.6.58898 > 192.168.2.245.8123: Flags [SEW], seq 361471277, win 64240, options [mss 1258,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
16:47:22.283327 IP 192.168.2.245.8123 > 192.168.0.6.58898: Flags [S.], seq 226116772, ack 361471278, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:47:22.375692 IP 192.168.0.6.58898 > 192.168.2.245.8123: Flags [.], ack 1, win 1027, length 0
16:47:22.375946 IP 192.168.0.6.58898 > 192.168.2.245.8123: Flags [P.], seq 1:601, ack 1, win 1027, length 600
16:47:22.375988 IP 192.168.2.245.8123 > 192.168.0.6.58898: Flags [.], ack 601, win 501, length 0
16:47:22.383365 IP 192.168.2.245.8123 > 192.168.0.6.58898: Flags [P.], seq 1:170, ack 601, win 501, length 169
16:47:22.383586 IP 192.168.2.245.8123 > 192.168.0.6.58898: Flags [P.], seq 170:230, ack 601, win 501, length 60
16:47:22.494391 IP 192.168.0.6.58898 > 192.168.2.245.8123: Flags [.], ack 230, win 1026, length 0
16:47:22.585272 IP 192.168.0.6.58898 > 192.168.2.245.8123: Flags [P.], seq 601:1431, ack 230, win 1026, length 830
16:47:22.585325 IP 192.168.2.245.8123 > 192.168.0.6.58898: Flags [.], ack 1431, win 501, length 0
16:47:22.593274 IP 192.168.2.245.8123 > 192.168.0.6.58898: Flags [P.], seq 230:400, ack 1431, win 501, length 170
16:47:22.594160 IP 192.168.2.245.8123 > 192.168.0.6.58898: Flags [P.], seq 400:570, ack 1431, win 501, length 170
16:47:22.693687 IP 192.168.0.6.58898 > 192.168.2.245.8123: Flags [.], ack 570, win 1024, length 0
```

However when the ask come from the internet 192.168.0.61 receive the ask but is not forwarded through as0t0. As example:

```
[root@192.168.0.61 ~]# tcpdump -i eth0 port 8123 -n
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
16:51:55.079366 IP 185.157.131.172.54673 > 192.168.0.61.8123: Flags [S], seq 331949659, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
16:51:55.759341 IP 185.157.131.172.54674 > 192.168.0.61.8123: Flags [S], seq 459540767, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
16:51:55.785218 IP 185.157.131.172.54675 > 192.168.0.61.8123: Flags [S], seq 3837920396, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
16:51:56.037321 IP 185.157.131.172.54676 > 192.168.0.61.8123: Flags [S], seq 1212264514, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
16:51:56.095399 IP 185.157.131.172.54673 > 192.168.0.61.8123: Flags [S], seq 331949659, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
16:51:56.775268 IP 185.157.131.172.54674 > 192.168.0.61.8123: Flags [S], seq 459540767, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
16:51:56.797301 IP 185.157.131.172.54675 > 192.168.0.61.8123: Flags [S], seq 3837920396, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
16:51:57.055209 IP 185.157.131.172.54676 > 192.168.0.61.8123: Flags [S], seq 1212264514, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
16:51:58.115261 IP 185.157.131.172.54673 > 192.168.0.61.8123: Flags [S], seq 331949659, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
16:51:58.799213 IP 185.157.131.172.54674 > 192.168.0.61.8123: Flags [S], seq 459540767, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
16:51:58.800187 IP 185.157.131.172.54675 > 192.168.0.61.8123: Flags [S], seq 3837920396, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
16:51:59.067247 IP 185.157.131.172.54676 > 192.168.0.61.8123: Flags [S], seq 1212264514, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
...



[root@192.168.0.61~]# tcpdump -i as0t0 port 8123 -n
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on as0t0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes


pi@192.168.2.245:~ $ sudo tcpdump -i tun0 port 8123 -n
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
```

I do not know how continue troubleshooting. Any idea?

Thanks

Edit 1:

```
[root@192.168.0.61 ~]# iptables-save -c
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Tue Oct 19 16:14:28 2021
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [47:10649]
:INPUT ACCEPT [560:148103]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [548:147705]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [548:147705]
:AS0_MANGLE_PRE_REL_EST - [0:0]
:AS0_MANGLE_TUN - [0:0]
[533:144894] -A PREROUTING -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j AS0_MANGLE_PRE_REL_EST
[2:251] -A PREROUTING -i as0t+ -j AS0_MANGLE_TUN
[533:144894] -A AS0_MANGLE_PRE_REL_EST -j ACCEPT
[2:251] -A AS0_MANGLE_TUN -j MARK --set-xmark 0x2000000/0xffffffff
[2:251] -A AS0_MANGLE_TUN -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Oct 19 16:14:28 2021
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Tue Oct 19 16:14:28 2021
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [611:161750]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [577:150493]
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Oct 19 16:14:28 2021
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Tue Oct 19 16:14:28 2021
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [7:1954]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [504:140983]
:AS0_ACCEPT - [0:0]
:AS0_IN - [0:0]
:AS0_IN_NAT - [0:0]
:AS0_IN_POST - [0:0]
:AS0_IN_PRE - [0:0]
:AS0_IN_ROUTE - [0:0]
:AS0_OUT - [0:0]
:AS0_OUT_LOCAL - [0:0]
:AS0_OUT_POST - [0:0]
:AS0_OUT_S2C - [0:0]
:AS0_U_OPENVPN_IN - [0:0]
:AS0_U_OPENVPN_OUT - [0:0]
:AS0_WEBACCEPT - [0:0]
[534:144934] -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j AS0_ACCEPT
[13:780] -A INPUT -i lo -j AS0_ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -m mark --mark 0x2000000/0x2000000 -j AS0_IN_PRE
[2:120] -A INPUT -d 192.168.0.61/32 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 1194 -j AS0_ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j AS0_WEBACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 943 -j AS0_WEBACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j AS0_ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -m mark --mark 0x2000000/0x2000000 -j AS0_IN_PRE
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o as0t+ -j AS0_OUT_S2C
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -o as0t+ -j AS0_OUT_LOCAL
[549:145834] -A AS0_ACCEPT -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_IN -d 172.27.224.1/32 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_IN -s 172.27.224.2/32 -j AS0_U_OPENVPN_IN
[0:0] -A AS0_IN -s 192.168.2.0/24 -j AS0_U_OPENVPN_IN
[0:0] -A AS0_IN -j AS0_IN_POST
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_NAT -j MARK --set-xmark 0x8000000/0x8000000
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_NAT -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_POST -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_POST -o as0t+ -j AS0_OUT
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_POST -j DROP
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_PRE -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j AS0_IN
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_PRE -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j AS0_IN
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_PRE -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j AS0_IN
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_PRE -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j AS0_IN
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_PRE -j DROP
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_ROUTE -j MARK --set-xmark 0x4000000/0x4000000
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_ROUTE -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_OUT -d 172.27.224.2/32 -j AS0_U_OPENVPN_OUT
[0:0] -A AS0_OUT -d 192.168.2.0/24 -j AS0_U_OPENVPN_OUT
[0:0] -A AS0_OUT -j AS0_OUT_POST
[0:0] -A AS0_OUT_LOCAL -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 5 -j DROP
[0:0] -A AS0_OUT_LOCAL -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_OUT_POST -j DROP
[0:0] -A AS0_OUT_S2C -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_OUT_S2C -j AS0_OUT
[0:0] -A AS0_U_OPENVPN_IN -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j AS0_IN_ROUTE
[0:0] -A AS0_U_OPENVPN_IN -j AS0_IN_POST
[0:0] -A AS0_U_OPENVPN_OUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_U_OPENVPN_OUT -s 192.168.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_U_OPENVPN_OUT -s 172.27.224.0/20 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_U_OPENVPN_OUT -j AS0_OUT_POST
[0:0] -A AS0_WEBACCEPT -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Oct 19 16:14:28 2021
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Tue Oct 19 16:14:28 2021
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [36:10120]
:INPUT ACCEPT [14:2429]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [18:1141]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [18:1141]
:AS0_NAT - [0:0]
:AS0_NAT_POST_REL_EST - [0:0]
:AS0_NAT_PRE - [0:0]
:AS0_NAT_PRE_REL_EST - [0:0]
:AS0_NAT_TEST - [0:0]
[0:0] -A PREROUTING -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j AS0_NAT_PRE_REL_EST
[0:0] -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1883 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.245:1883
[0:0] -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1884 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.245:1884
[0:0] -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8123 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.245:8123
[0:0] -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2223 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.245:22
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j AS0_NAT_POST_REL_EST
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -m mark --mark 0x2000000/0x2000000 -j AS0_NAT_PRE
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.61
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_POST_REL_EST -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_PRE -m mark --mark 0x8000000/0x8000000 -j AS0_NAT
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_PRE -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j AS0_NAT_TEST
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_PRE -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j AS0_NAT_TEST
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_PRE -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j AS0_NAT_TEST
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_PRE -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j AS0_NAT_TEST
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_PRE -j AS0_NAT
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_PRE_REL_EST -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_TEST -o as0t+ -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_TEST -m mark --mark 0x4000000/0x4000000 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_TEST -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_TEST -d 192.168.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_TEST -d 172.27.224.0/20 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_TEST -j AS0_NAT
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Oct 19 16:14:28 202
```

Edit 2:
As @a-b suggest I give more info about the network layout, because there is a openVPN tunnel (routing) which may be filtering some packets. The openVPN tunnel is represented as a ray.

[image: Network layout]
In the examples 192.168.0.6 can go through the tunnel, but public ip (185.157.131.172) not.

Comment: Please add the output of this in your question: `iptables-save -c`.(ie: the whole firewall, not an excerpt). Also as0t0 appears to not be Ethernet-like but probably some kind of layer 3 tunnel. So any additional information about the real network layout could also help.

Comment: I have just edited the post adding the output of iptables-save -c.

Comment: Yes, the network layout is a bit more complex, but I try to keep the question as simple as possible.
192.168.0.61 is a OpenVPN AS server (as0t0) and 192.168.2.245 is a OpenVPN client (tun0). But as far as I know there is no problem with that, as 192.168.2.245 is accesible from 192.168.0.0/24 without problems.

Comment: I would insert (rather than append) a rule in the filter FORWARD chain to allow traffic between eth0 and as0t0 and the other way around to check it's an iptables problem and not a routing problem. Then I'd check the tool which generated these rules (they don't look made by hand, do they?) to see how to enable the blocked traffic. I don't really see how to make an answer with these rules around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @A.B suggestion I looked at OpenVPN AS settings, which generate a lot of iptables rules. I modified one field that was:

```
Routing
Specify the private subnets to which all clients should be given access (one per line): 
192.168.0.0/24
```

By:

```
Routing
Specify the private subnets to which all clients should be given access (one per line): 
192.168.0.0/24
0.0.0.0/0
```

Now packets with a public IP are forwared from *eth0* to *as0t0* with no problem and all is working.

If now I do a iptables-save -c I get:

```
[root@192.168.0.61 ~]# iptables-save -c
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Oct 20 16:25:06 2021
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [232:55794]
:INPUT ACCEPT [2986:381728]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [15:2541]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2929:1099682]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2944:1102223]
:AS0_MANGLE_PRE_REL_EST - [0:0]
:AS0_MANGLE_TUN - [0:0]
[2899:374408] -A PREROUTING -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j AS0_MANGLE_PRE_REL_EST
[12:1506] -A PREROUTING -i as0t+ -j AS0_MANGLE_TUN
[2899:374408] -A AS0_MANGLE_PRE_REL_EST -j ACCEPT
[12:1506] -A AS0_MANGLE_TUN -j MARK --set-xmark 0x2000000/0xffffffff
[12:1506] -A AS0_MANGLE_TUN -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Oct 20 16:25:06 2021
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Oct 20 16:25:06 2021
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [3175:434235]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2972:1103685]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Oct 20 16:25:06 2021
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Oct 20 16:25:06 2021
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [61:5708]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2839:1062541]
:AS0_ACCEPT - [0:0]
:AS0_IN - [0:0]
:AS0_IN_NAT - [0:0]
:AS0_IN_POST - [0:0]
:AS0_IN_PRE - [0:0]
:AS0_IN_ROUTE - [0:0]
:AS0_OUT - [0:0]
:AS0_OUT_LOCAL - [0:0]
:AS0_OUT_POST - [0:0]
:AS0_OUT_S2C - [0:0]
:AS0_U_OPENVPN_IN - [0:0]
:AS0_U_OPENVPN_OUT - [0:0]
:AS0_WEBACCEPT - [0:0]
[2900:374448] -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j AS0_ACCEPT
[14:840] -A INPUT -i lo -j AS0_ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -m mark --mark 0x2000000/0x2000000 -j AS0_IN_PRE
[1:60] -A INPUT -d 192.168.0.61/32 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 1194 -j AS0_ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j AS0_WEBACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 943 -j AS0_WEBACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j AS0_ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -m mark --mark 0x2000000/0x2000000 -j AS0_IN_PRE
[15:2541] -A FORWARD -o as0t+ -j AS0_OUT_S2C
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -o as0t+ -j AS0_OUT_LOCAL
[2915:375348] -A AS0_ACCEPT -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_IN -d 172.27.224.1/32 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_IN -s 172.27.224.2/32 -j AS0_U_OPENVPN_IN
[0:0] -A AS0_IN -s 192.168.2.0/24 -j AS0_U_OPENVPN_IN
[0:0] -A AS0_IN -j AS0_IN_POST
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_NAT -j MARK --set-xmark 0x8000000/0x8000000
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_NAT -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_POST -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_POST -o as0t+ -j AS0_OUT
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_POST -j DROP
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_PRE -j AS0_IN
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_PRE -j DROP
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_ROUTE -j MARK --set-xmark 0x4000000/0x4000000
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_ROUTE -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_OUT -d 172.27.224.2/32 -j AS0_U_OPENVPN_OUT
[0:0] -A AS0_OUT -d 192.168.2.0/24 -j AS0_U_OPENVPN_OUT
[0:0] -A AS0_OUT -j AS0_OUT_POST
[0:0] -A AS0_OUT_LOCAL -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 5 -j DROP
[0:0] -A AS0_OUT_LOCAL -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_OUT_POST -j DROP
[15:2541] -A AS0_OUT_S2C -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_OUT_S2C -j AS0_OUT
[0:0] -A AS0_U_OPENVPN_IN -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j AS0_IN_ROUTE
[0:0] -A AS0_U_OPENVPN_IN -j AS0_IN_POST
[0:0] -A AS0_U_OPENVPN_OUT -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_U_OPENVPN_OUT -s 192.168.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_U_OPENVPN_OUT -s 172.27.224.0/20 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_U_OPENVPN_OUT -j AS0_OUT_POST
[0:0] -A AS0_WEBACCEPT -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Oct 20 16:25:06 2021
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Oct 20 16:25:06 2021
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [207:53029]
:INPUT ACCEPT [63:5230]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [19:1202]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [21:1562]
:AS0_NAT - [0:0]
:AS0_NAT_POST_REL_EST - [0:0]
:AS0_NAT_PRE - [0:0]
:AS0_NAT_PRE_REL_EST - [0:0]
:AS0_NAT_TEST - [0:0]
[0:0] -A PREROUTING -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j AS0_NAT_PRE_REL_EST
[0:0] -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1883 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.245:1883
[0:0] -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1884 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.245:1884
[0:0] -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8123 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.245:8123
[0:0] -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2223 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.245:22
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j AS0_NAT_POST_REL_EST
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -m mark --mark 0x2000000/0x2000000 -j AS0_NAT_PRE
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.61
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_POST_REL_EST -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_PRE -m mark --mark 0x8000000/0x8000000 -j AS0_NAT
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_PRE -j AS0_NAT_TEST
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_PRE -j AS0_NAT
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_PRE_REL_EST -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_TEST -o as0t+ -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_TEST -m mark --mark 0x4000000/0x4000000 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_TEST -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_TEST -j AS0_NAT
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Oct 20 16:25:06 2021[root@centoscwp ~]# iptables-save -c
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Oct 20 16:25:06 2021
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [232:55794]
:INPUT ACCEPT [2986:381728]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [15:2541]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2929:1099682]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2944:1102223]
:AS0_MANGLE_PRE_REL_EST - [0:0]
:AS0_MANGLE_TUN - [0:0]
[2899:374408] -A PREROUTING -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j AS0_MANGLE_PRE_REL_EST
[12:1506] -A PREROUTING -i as0t+ -j AS0_MANGLE_TUN
[2899:374408] -A AS0_MANGLE_PRE_REL_EST -j ACCEPT
[12:1506] -A AS0_MANGLE_TUN -j MARK --set-xmark 0x2000000/0xffffffff
[12:1506] -A AS0_MANGLE_TUN -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Oct 20 16:25:06 2021
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Oct 20 16:25:06 2021
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [3175:434235]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2972:1103685]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Oct 20 16:25:06 2021
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Oct 20 16:25:06 2021
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [61:5708]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2839:1062541]
:AS0_ACCEPT - [0:0]
:AS0_IN - [0:0]
:AS0_IN_NAT - [0:0]
:AS0_IN_POST - [0:0]
:AS0_IN_PRE - [0:0]
:AS0_IN_ROUTE - [0:0]
:AS0_OUT - [0:0]
:AS0_OUT_LOCAL - [0:0]
:AS0_OUT_POST - [0:0]
:AS0_OUT_S2C - [0:0]
:AS0_U_OPENVPN_IN - [0:0]
:AS0_U_OPENVPN_OUT - [0:0]
:AS0_WEBACCEPT - [0:0]
[2900:374448] -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j AS0_ACCEPT
[14:840] -A INPUT -i lo -j AS0_ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -m mark --mark 0x2000000/0x2000000 -j AS0_IN_PRE
[1:60] -A INPUT -d 192.168.0.61/32 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 1194 -j AS0_ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j AS0_WEBACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 943 -j AS0_WEBACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j AS0_ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -m mark --mark 0x2000000/0x2000000 -j AS0_IN_PRE
[15:2541] -A FORWARD -o as0t+ -j AS0_OUT_S2C
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -o as0t+ -j AS0_OUT_LOCAL
[2915:375348] -A AS0_ACCEPT -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_IN -d 172.27.224.1/32 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_IN -s 172.27.224.2/32 -j AS0_U_OPENVPN_IN
[0:0] -A AS0_IN -s 192.168.2.0/24 -j AS0_U_OPENVPN_IN
[0:0] -A AS0_IN -j AS0_IN_POST
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_NAT -j MARK --set-xmark 0x8000000/0x8000000
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_NAT -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_POST -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_POST -o as0t+ -j AS0_OUT
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_POST -j DROP
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_PRE -j AS0_IN
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_PRE -j DROP
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_ROUTE -j MARK --set-xmark 0x4000000/0x4000000
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_ROUTE -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_OUT -d 172.27.224.2/32 -j AS0_U_OPENVPN_OUT
[0:0] -A AS0_OUT -d 192.168.2.0/24 -j AS0_U_OPENVPN_OUT
[0:0] -A AS0_OUT -j AS0_OUT_POST
[0:0] -A AS0_OUT_LOCAL -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 5 -j DROP
[0:0] -A AS0_OUT_LOCAL -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_OUT_POST -j DROP
[15:2541] -A AS0_OUT_S2C -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_OUT_S2C -j AS0_OUT
[0:0] -A AS0_U_OPENVPN_IN -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j AS0_IN_ROUTE
[0:0] -A AS0_U_OPENVPN_IN -j AS0_IN_POST
[0:0] -A AS0_U_OPENVPN_OUT -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_U_OPENVPN_OUT -s 192.168.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_U_OPENVPN_OUT -s 172.27.224.0/20 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_U_OPENVPN_OUT -j AS0_OUT_POST
[0:0] -A AS0_WEBACCEPT -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Oct 20 16:25:06 2021
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Oct 20 16:25:06 2021
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [207:53029]
:INPUT ACCEPT [63:5230]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [19:1202]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [21:1562]
:AS0_NAT - [0:0]
:AS0_NAT_POST_REL_EST - [0:0]
:AS0_NAT_PRE - [0:0]
:AS0_NAT_PRE_REL_EST - [0:0]
:AS0_NAT_TEST - [0:0]
[0:0] -A PREROUTING -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j AS0_NAT_PRE_REL_EST
[0:0] -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1883 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.245:1883
[0:0] -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1884 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.245:1884
[0:0] -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8123 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.245:8123
[0:0] -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2223 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.245:22
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j AS0_NAT_POST_REL_EST
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -m mark --mark 0x2000000/0x2000000 -j AS0_NAT_PRE
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.61
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_POST_REL_EST -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_PRE -m mark --mark 0x8000000/0x8000000 -j AS0_NAT
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_PRE -j AS0_NAT_TEST
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_PRE -j AS0_NAT
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_PRE_REL_EST -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_TEST -o as0t+ -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_TEST -m mark --mark 0x4000000/0x4000000 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_TEST -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_TEST -j AS0_NAT
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Oct 20 16:25:06 2021
```

As you can see some rules has been changed, like:
before:

```
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_POST -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_OUT_S2C -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_U_OPENVPN_OUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_PRE -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j AS0_NAT_TEST
```

after:

```
[0:0] -A AS0_IN_POST -j ACCEPT
[15:2541] -A AS0_OUT_S2C -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_U_OPENVPN_OUT -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A AS0_NAT_PRE -j AS0_NAT_TEST
```

I attach a screenshot of the OpenVPN setting I have changed
[image]